# Быстрый способ получить скриншот экрана c++

Tags: c++

Как можно быстро получить скриншот экрана что бы было минимум нагрузки на пк и получал изображение быстро? Пробовал GDI - с использованием BitBit, PrintWindow - долговато, нагрузка на пк. Пробовал DirectX9 - через GetFrontBufferData, очень долго, на счет нагрузки не знаю. Может с более новейшим DirectX будет быстрее?

Comment: Поискал *за вас* - см., например, на этом же сайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/746167/195342

Comment: Следует использовать Desktop Duplication API.

Comment: а можно ли через Desktop Duplication API получить скриншот окна какого нить? Что то типо функции PrintWindow